# Ionic 4 How to get data from another page

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm navigating page and send data to page. i want to know how can i get data i send to the page ? .

Example: In ionic 3 we push page and send data like this

```
this.navCtrl.push(Page, {x:x})
```

And in other page we get date from navParams like

```
this.navParams.get('x');
```

I need to know how ill get data in ionic 4 ? 
Im navigating page and data like this

```
details(y){
 this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/packagedetails',{y:y});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use navigaionExtras to achieve this

page1:

```
  let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
          state: {
            x: x
          }
        };
        this.router.navigate(['details'], navigationExtras);
```

page2:

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
          if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
            this.data = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.x;
          }
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

They are many way to do it. Here is three:

### First

This is a one page parameter to another, but nothing is saved if the user close the app (not sure at 100%, but if I remember well it isn't):

page 1:

```
import {Router} from "@angular/router" 

@Component(thingsThatIsIt)

export class Page1Page{
  constructor(private router: Router,OthersThingsInYourConstructor){thingsThatIsIt} 


  FunctionToGoOnPage2(someParameters) //someParameters is an JS object (like JSON for exemple)
  {
    this.router.navigate(["Page2",someParameters])
  }
}
```

page 2:

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router" 

@Component(thingsThatIsIt)

export class Page2Page{
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,OthersThingsInYourConstructor)
  {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params)
      FunctionThatDealWithParameters(params)
    })
  }




  FunctionThatDealWithParameters(someParameters) //someParameters is an JS object (like JSON for exemple)
  {
    //code to use your parameters
  }
}
```

### Second

This is a one page to many others, but nothing is saved if the user close the app:

make a service: `ionic generate service`

in this service, create some attributes, and some get and set method.

in a page that need your service, for getting or setting method, you just have to import it, and call your get/set method (the one you need by the way)

### Third

This is a one page to many others, and everything is save, even if the user close his app:

use the [ionic local storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage)