# IONIC-4 Navigation - how get parameter passed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Iam new to Ionic - 4.
I have function which is navigated to my items page.

```
 gradeItem = function(data){
     this.navCtrl.navigate('grade/items', {data:data});
 }
```

and it is successfully navigating.

Now I want to access my parameter `data` from my `items.page.ts` file.

can anyone please help me on this.I tried `navParams` but it throwing error like

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ItemsPage -> NavParams]:`

Comment: like this parameter is passed .check this link https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-pass-data-between-pages/139601

Comment: can you sent appmoule.ts or itemmodulets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 4 How to get data from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56415132/ionic-4-how-to-get-data-from-another-page)